# PHP preg_replace_callback() Compilation failed: missing )

Tags: php, compiler-errors, anonymous-function

ok i do have this small helper function

```
public static function toJSON($arr){
        $json = json_encode($arr);
        return preg_replace_callback('/(?<=:)"function((?:(?!}").)*}"/',
                                    function($string){
                                        return str_replace(array('\"','/','"','n','t'),array('"','/','"','',''),substr($string[0],1,-1));
                                     },$json);
    }
```

now what i did there was i created a anonymous function for the callback of preg_replace_callback() function, i checked 3 times already if i missed a single parentheses but  my IDE(zend studio) seems not to show any unclosed parentheses.

my error is this

> preg_replace_callback() Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 30
>   (X:\xampp\htdocs\aya\protected\xxx\xxxArray.php:180

where i got wrong?

**NOTE**: the purpose of this small helper function is to let me create anonymous function inside my json output. if you can recommend me a much better script it would be a big help for me..

Comment: dont make things complex. do step by step

Comment: well hmm... where is the complexity there?

Comment: get yourself a good syntax highlighting editor with brace matching feature. try notepad2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the original author meant to do:

```
'/(?<=:)"function((?:(?!}").)*})"/'
                               ^
```

If you would want to capture the function body (with the arguments) for the replacing later, however the replace function uses the `0` index (the whole match) later so you can remove the first `(` too:

```
'/(?<=:)"function(?:(?!}").)*}"/'
                 ^
                 +-- a "(" deleted
```

This will work too (eats a little less memory as well).

Answer (score 1):

There is an unclosed parenthesis in

```
'/(?<=:)"function((?:(?!}").)*}"/'
```

The editor won't spot it as it won't validate content in strings.